# Is this true? Oscillation of $f$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

A friend of mine and I are at odds over the following statement:

Given that $x$ lies in the interior of the domain of a function, $f$, the oscillation of $f$ at $x$ is ALWAYS defined.

I think this is false. Consider the oscillation of $1/x$ at $x=0$ and let's define $f(0)=0$.

What do you guys say?

Comment: Well, the first thing is to ask whether $x = 0$ is in the domain of $1/x$ ...

Comment: How is $x=0$ on the interior of the domain of the function $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}$?

Comment: I just fixed that. Now is the statement true? If yes, please provide an argument or if no, does the counterexample work?

Comment: What is your definition of oscillation? If $f$ is defined on a subset $A$ of $X$ then one reasonable definition of the oscillation of $f$ at a point $x \in X$ is $$\inf\{\operatorname{diam}f(U \cap A) \mid U \text{ open, } x \in U \} \in [0,\infty]$$ and you don't even need $f$ to be defined at $x$.

Comment: The definition I am following is: $\lim{r \to O^+} $diam $f[x-r,x+r]$

Comment: So you are taking the limit of a monotonic sequence, which is well-defined as an element of $[0,\infty]$, but not *necessarily* as a real number, as indicated in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this depends on what you consider to be defined. Using the exact statement you've claimed, I would say that the oscillation of $1/x$ at $x = 0$ is not a counterexample because $x = 0$ is not in the domain of the function.

In general, however, we can simply avoid this restriction. The supremum of $1/x$ about $x = 0$ *is* $+\infty$, and the infimum of $1/x$ about $x = 0$ *is* $-\infty$, so if you're defining the oscillation directly in that manner, then the oscillation of $1/x$ about $x = 0$ is $+\infty$.

Comment: But can't one say that the oscillation is not defined since it is +inf and it is NOT a real number?

Comment: Again, that depends on what you mean by defined. I would say that having oscillation $+\infty$ is perfectly well-defined. However, if both infimum and supremum are $+\infty$, then I would say that the oscillation is *not* defined since $\infty - \infty$ is not well-defined.